# How to allow a bigger avatar (image) in the twitter bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a dropdown menu like in gmail, wordpress and many other apps where the user can click on his avatar to select an menu item.

Here is what I have done and that works only if I keep my avatar size to 19x19. If I try increasing its size, it messes up my nav bar.

Any suggestions?

```
<ul class="nav pull-right" id="main-menu-right"  style='font-size:12px;'>
    <% if signed_in? %>
        <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" id="dropUser" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">

            <%= current_user.avatar_file_name.nil? ? raw("<i class='icon-user'></i>") : image_tag(current_user.avatar.url(:square_tiny), size: '19x19', class: "img-rounded") %>
            <b class="caret"></b>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropUser">       
                 <li><%= link_to raw("<i class='icon-user'></i> My Profile"), "/user_profiles/show", :tabindex => "-1" %></li>

                 <li class="divider"></li>
                 <li><%= link_to raw("<i class='icon-dashboard'></i> Admin dashboard"), admin_dashboard_path, :tabindex => "-1" if current_user.has_role? :admin %></li>
                 <li><%= link_to( raw("<i class='icon-off'></i> Logout"), destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %></li>
            </ul>
              </a>
         </li>
    <% else %>   
        <li>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <%= link_to(raw("<i class='icon-lock'></i> Sign in"), new_user_session_path, :class => 'btn',  style: 'font-size:12px;') %> 
            <%= link_to(raw("Sign up"), new_registration_path(resource_name), :class => 'btn',  style: 'font-size:12px;') %>
        </div>
        </li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: can you provide a test page?

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
        <div class="nav navbar-right">
            <div class="navbar-text">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" class="profile-image img-circle">
                <a href="#">Username</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar .profile-image{
    margin: -10px 0px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: the cleaner solution that i found

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of the default line hieght for the menu items. Could you make your layout work if you moved the avatar out of the UL like this? http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/dJS2k/

I have the profile link on the left of the avatar, but there's no reason why you couldn't position it underneath.

I know it's not exactly what you describe but it lets you use any size avatar. The general html would be:

```
<navbar>
<img src="avatar.jpg" class="pull-right">
  <ul class="pull-right">
    <li class="dropdown"><li></li>
  </ul>
</navbar>
```